Getting an error that the LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated
I have C# application (.NET Core 4) and I have written the following LINQ expression for getting list of assigned tickets from database view.
public async Task<List<TicketSchedulerDTO>> GetAssignedTickets(ScheduleFilterDTO dTO, List<string> BranchIdList)
{
    try
    {
        return await context.TicketView
            .Where(x => BranchIdList.Contains(x.BranchId.ToString()))
            .Where(t => t.ScheduleDateTime <= dTO.EndDate && t.ScheduleDateTime >= dTO.StartDate && t.StatusId != 1 && t.StatusId != 7)
           .Select(x => new TicketSchedulerDTO
           {
               Id = x.Id,
               CallDateTime = x.CallDateTime,
               Start = x.ScheduleDateTime,
               CompleteDateTime = x.CompleteDateTime,
               TotalEstimate = x.TotalEstimate,
               End = GetEndFromEstimate(x.ScheduleDateTime, x.TotalEstimate, dTO.WorkDayEnd),
               Title = MOM.Alias.Common.DTO.TicketID + " " + x.Id,
               Description = x.Reason,
               Address = x.Address,
               City = x.City,
               StateName = x.StateName,
               CountryName = x.CountryName,
               WorkerId = x.WorkerId,
               WorkerName = (x.WorkerId == null) ? MOM.Alias.Common.DTO.UnassignedTicket : x.WorkerName,
               CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
               LocationName = x.LocationName,
               Equipment = x.Equipment,
               StatusId = x.StatusId,
               StatusName = x.StatusName,
               StatusColor = x.StatusColor,
               Longitude = x.Longitude,
               Latitude = x.Latitude,
               BranchName = x.BranchName,
               CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
               WorkComplete = x.WorkComplete,
               EnteredBy = x.EnteredBy,
               IsCharge = x.IsCharge,
               IsDocument = x.IsDocumentExist,
               DispatchAlert = x.DispatchAlert,
               IsSignature = x.IsSigned,
               IsReviewed = x.IsReviewed,
               IsTimesheet = x.IsTimesheet,
               InvoiceId = x.InvoiceId,
               RecurringDate = x.RecurringDate,
               OverTime = x.OverTime,
               IsPayroll = x.IsPayroll,
               Icon = context.TicketCategory.Where(y => y.Id == x.CategoryId).Select(y => y.Icon).FirstOrDefault(),
           })
           .Where(y =>
                (dTO.TicketCategoryIDs == null
                || dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Any()
                || dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Contains(0)
                || dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Any(z => z == y.CategoryId)) &&
                (dTO.TicketStatusIDs == null
                || dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Any()
                || dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Contains(0)
                || dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Any(z => z == y.StatusId)) &&
                 (dTO.WorkerIDs == null
                || dTO.WorkerIDs.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.WorkerIDs.Any()
                || dTO.WorkerIDs.Contains(0)
                || dTO.WorkerIDs.Any(z => z == y.WorkerId)) &&
                (dTO.LocationIDs == null
                || dTO.LocationIDs.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.LocationIDs.Any()
                || dTO.LocationIDs.Contains(0)
                || dTO.LocationIDs.Any(z => z == y.LocationId)) &&
                (dTO.DepartmentIDs == null
                || dTO.DepartmentIDs.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.DepartmentIDs.Any()
                || dTO.DepartmentIDs.Contains(0)
                || dTO.DepartmentIDs.Any(z => z == y.DepartmentId)) &&
                (dTO.SupervisorID == null
                || dTO.SupervisorID.Count() == 0
                || !dTO.SupervisorID.Any()
                || dTO.SupervisorID.Contains(0)
                || dTO.SupervisorID.Intersect(dTO.WorkerIDs).Any())
           ).ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

Whenever this expression is executed i get the following error
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '__dTO_TicketCategoryIDs_4
    .Any(e0 => (int?)(int)e0 == (int?)new TicketSchedulerDTO{ 
        Id = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Id, 
        CallDateTime = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).CallDateTime, 
        Start = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).ScheduleDateTime, 
        CompleteDateTime = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).CompleteDateTime, 
        TotalEstimate = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).TotalEstimate, 
        End = SchedulerRepository.GetEndFromEstimate(
            scheduleDateTime: StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
                StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
                ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
                IsNullable: False).ScheduleDateTime, 
            totalEstimate: StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
                StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
                ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
                IsNullable: False).TotalEstimate, 
            workEnd: __dTO_WorkDayEnd_3), 
        Title = "Ticket ID " + (object)StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Id, 
        Description = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Reason, 
        Address = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Address, 
        City = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).City, 
        StateName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).StateName, 
        CountryName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).CountryName, 
        WorkerId = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).WorkerId, 
        WorkerName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).WorkerId == null ? "Unassigned Ticket" : StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).WorkerName, 
        CategoryName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).CategoryName, 
        LocationName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).LocationName, 
        Equipment = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Equipment, 
        StatusId = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).StatusId, 
        StatusName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).StatusName, 
        StatusColor = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).StatusColor, 
        Longitude = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Longitude, 
        Latitude = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).Latitude, 
        BranchName = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).BranchName, 
        CreatedBy = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).CreatedBy, 
        WorkComplete = (bool?)StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).WorkComplete, 
        EnteredBy = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).EnteredBy, 
        IsCharge = (bool?)StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsCharge, 
        IsDocument = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsDocumentExist, 
        DispatchAlert = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).DispatchAlert, 
        IsSignature = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsSigned, 
        IsReviewed = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsReviewed, 
        IsTimesheet = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsTimesheet, 
        InvoiceId = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).InvoiceId, 
        RecurringDate = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).RecurringDate, 
        OverTime = StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).OverTime, 
        IsPayroll = (bool?)StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
            StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
            ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False).IsPayroll, 
        Icon = DbSet<TicketCategory>()
            .Where(t0 => (int?)(int)t0.Id == (int?)StructuralTypeShaperExpression(
                StructuralType: MOM.Infrastructure.Schedule.Entities.TicketView
                ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
                IsNullable: False).CategoryId)
            .Select(t0 => t0.Icon)
            .FirstOrDefault() 
    }
    .CategoryId)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

I do not know what is causing this issue as the same filters are working fine for local testing.
Please advise how can I resolve this issue.

I would start by trying to reduce this to a minimal query that fails. Is the problem due to the filter, or due to the projection, for example? What's the minimal set of properties that causes the problem? My guess is that the problem is with WorkerName, but that's something that you should do the work to diagnose.

"I have C# application (.NET Core 4)" No you don't, there is no .NET Core 4.

At first signt CategoryId, LocationId, DepartmentId are missing from projection, query will fail to translate. Also this condition is strange dTO.SupervisorID.Intersect(dTO.WorkerIDs).Any()

Too much invisible code, like the TicketView class, MOM.Alias.Common.DTO, ScheduleFilterDTO, this GetEndFromEstimate method. Try to review your post like a random reader when asking questions.

EF Core tries to translate your LINQ query to SQL, but it cannot translate the method call GetEndFromEstimate, because this function does not exist in SQL. Therefore, you must perform the Select part of the query locally as LINQ-to-Objects. You can do this by splitting the database part of the query from the objects part with ToListAsync.
Something like this:
// Database query
var temp = await context.TicketView
    .Where(x => BranchIdList.Contains(x.BranchId.ToString()))
    .Where(t => t.ScheduleDateTime <= dTO.EndDate && t.ScheduleDateTime >= dTO.StartDate && t.StatusId != 1 && t.StatusId != 7)
    .ToListAsync();

// Local query
return temp
    .Select(x => new TicketSchedulerDTO
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        CallDateTime = x.CallDateTime,
        ...
        // This will be performed locally now:
        End = GetEndFromEstimate(x.ScheduleDateTime, x.TotalEstimate, dTO.WorkDayEnd),
        ...
    }).Where(y => ...
    ).ToList();

Note that it would reduce the network traffic, if you could execute the Where that follows the Select in the database part, as this would reduce the number of returned records.
Note also that you can combine several Where filters into one by combining their conditions with &&.

There's no need for that, you can just move the final Where earlier.

@Charlieface, I gave the advice to move the Where earlier, but there is still the Select to be done which is calling this GetEndFromEstimate function.

The issue as noted by others is that some of your functions are client-side functions, which cannot be executed on the serve.
The real solution is to reorder your query so that the Where predicates are all executed on the server, and the Select projection is at the end.

You can also improve your query by dynamically adding conditions. This will be more efficient than using those giant || OR conditions inside the Where.
BranchIdList clearly needs to be a list of numbers not of strings. This will also be more efficient.
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; does absolutely nothing except wipe the stack trace. If you need to re-throw then use throw;, but don't catch at all if you aren't going to handle the error.

public async Task<List<TicketSchedulerDTO>> GetAssignedTickets(ScheduleFilterDTO dTO, List<int> BranchIdList)
{
    var query = context.TicketView
        .Where(t =>
            BranchIdList.Contains(t.BranchId)
            && t.ScheduleDateTime <= dTO.EndDate
            && t.ScheduleDateTime >= dTO.StartDate
            && t.StatusId != 1
            && t.StatusId != 7
        );

    if (dTO.TicketCategoryIDs is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Contains(0))
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.TicketCategoryIDs.Any(z => z == t.CategoryId));

    if (dTO.TicketStatusIDs is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Contains(0))
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.TicketStatusIDs.Any(z => z == t.StatusId));

    if (dTO.WorkerIDs is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.WorkerIDs.Contains(0))
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.WorkerIDs.Any(z => z == t.WorkerId));

    if (dTO.LocationIDs is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.LocationIDs.Contains(0))
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.LocationIDs.Any(z => z == t.LocationId));

    if (dTO.DepartmentIDs is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.DepartmentIDs.Contains(0))
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.DepartmentIDs.Any(z => z == t.DepartmentId));

    if (dTO.SupervisorID is not { Count : > 0 } && !dTO.SupervisorID.Contains(0) && !dTO.SupervisorID.Intersect(dTO.WorkerIDs).Any())
        query = query.Where(t => dTO.SupervisorID.Any(z => z == t.WorkerId));

    return await query
           .Select(x => new TicketSchedulerDTO
           {
               Id = x.Id,
               CallDateTime = x.CallDateTime,
               Start = x.ScheduleDateTime,
               CompleteDateTime = x.CompleteDateTime,
               TotalEstimate = x.TotalEstimate,
               End = GetEndFromEstimate(x.ScheduleDateTime, x.TotalEstimate, dTO.WorkDayEnd),
               Title = MOM.Alias.Common.DTO.TicketID + " " + x.Id,
               Description = x.Reason,
               Address = x.Address,
               City = x.City,
               StateName = x.StateName,
               CountryName = x.CountryName,
               WorkerId = x.WorkerId,
               WorkerName = (x.WorkerId == null) ? MOM.Alias.Common.DTO.UnassignedTicket : x.WorkerName,
               CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
               LocationName = x.LocationName,
               Equipment = x.Equipment,
               StatusId = x.StatusId,
               StatusName = x.StatusName,
               StatusColor = x.StatusColor,
               Longitude = x.Longitude,
               Latitude = x.Latitude,
               BranchName = x.BranchName,
               CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
               WorkComplete = x.WorkComplete,
               EnteredBy = x.EnteredBy,
               IsCharge = x.IsCharge,
               IsDocument = x.IsDocumentExist,
               DispatchAlert = x.DispatchAlert,
               IsSignature = x.IsSigned,
               IsReviewed = x.IsReviewed,
               IsTimesheet = x.IsTimesheet,
               InvoiceId = x.InvoiceId,
               RecurringDate = x.RecurringDate,
               OverTime = x.OverTime,
               IsPayroll = x.IsPayroll,
               Icon = context.TicketCategory.Where(y => y.Id == x.CategoryId).Select(y => y.Icon).FirstOrDefault(),
           })
           .ToListAsync();

A final note: there are clearly many columns on this table that are not properly normalized, such as StatusName or LocationName which should be in separate tables/entities.
